# Hide the URL when using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, security, restful-url

I have the following code:

```
urlString = "..."
URL url = new URL(urlString);         
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

How can I make urlString secure and still working? By secure I mean from viewing the APK and seeing the url itself, or is it a lost cause because any simple sniffer will know the URL anyway? if so, what can be done about it?

Comment: you mean securing in a way so that decompiling apk will not show your url or some thing else ?

Comment: exactly. I'm less familiar with APK structure but in the past, viewing an EXE file,even with notepad! all the strings were out in the open.

Comment: don't declare your string in class but get a reference from Strings.xml

Comment: I build the string on the go (attach it the params) so I can't use a fixed string from strings.xml

Comment: Maybe you can store the base url in the Strings.xml file and then add params to that.